# How to enable diagnostics tracing for LSP in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, vsix, language-server-protocol

I'm trying to enable diagnostics tracing for LSP in Visual Studio like written in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-an-lsp-extension?view=vs-2019#enable-diagnostics-tracing).

According to the instructions, I did the following steps:

1. I've added the `ConfigurationSections` to the `ILanguageClient`

   ```
   public IEnumerable<string> ConfigurationSections
   {
       get
       {
           yield return "foo";
       }
   }
   ```
2. I created VSWorkspaceSettings.json file the following line:

   ```
   {
      "foo.trace.server": "Verbose"
   }
   ```
3. I added the VSWorkspaceSettings.json file to the .vs folder where the `ILanguageClient` is written and the .vs folder of the solution that the LSP is implemented for.

But, it doesn't work. What I'm missing? Maybe I copy the VSWorkspaceSettings.json file to the wrong folder?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find how to enable it, but I found another way to get all the JSON requests from the visual studio.
In the Language client-side, I intercepted all the requests from Visual studio by creating `InterceptionStream` like [here](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2015/06/c-how-to-record-what-gets-written-to-or.html) and I wrap the PipeStream.

The Usage:

```
var readerPipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(readerPipeName);
var writerPipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(writerPipeName);
var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(logFilePath);
var interceptionStream = new InterceptionStream(writerPipe, fileStream);

if (process.Start())
{
     await Task.WhenAll(readerPipe.ConnectAsync(token), writerPipe.ConnectAsync(token));
     return new Connection(readerPipe, interceptionStream);
}
```

The `InterceptionStream`:

```
public class InterceptionStream : Stream
{
    public InterceptionStream(Stream innerStream, Stream copyStream)
    {
        InnerStream = innerStream ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerStream));
        CopyStream = copyStream ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(copyStream));

        if (!CopyStream.CanWrite)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("copyStream is not writable");
        }
    }

    public Stream InnerStream { get; }

    public Stream CopyStream { get; }

    public override bool CanRead => InnerStream.CanRead;

    public override bool CanSeek => InnerStream.CanSeek;

    public override bool CanWrite => InnerStream.CanWrite;

    public override long Length => InnerStream.Length;

    public override long Position
    {
        get => InnerStream.Position;
        set => InnerStream.Position = value;
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        InnerStream.Flush();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return InnerStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        InnerStream.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var bytesRead = InnerStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        if (bytesRead != 0)
        {
            CopyStream.Write(buffer, offset, bytesRead);
        }

        return bytesRead;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        InnerStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        CopyStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        CopyStream.Dispose();
        InnerStream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: The top part of this answer seems to deal specifically with the example project, which configures its own log, skip to the bottom for the client log location.**

I struggled with enabling this (also using the guide you linked). I'm not entirely sure if I've "solved" it, but these steps certainly helped me obtain logs:

I manually created the folder `%Temp%\VisualStudio\LSP`, after doing this using the Microsoft demo LSP project, a `MockLog.svclog` started appeared when I ran the language server.

If you create the `VSWorkspaceSettings.json` as suggested, it seems to need to be placed in the `.vs` folder related to the project you're **opening** with the test Visual Studio instance; I was using TestFiles Folder, and placing it inside the '.vs` folder created in there.

That seems to be reflected in the logs, but it did not seem to make any difference to the initial output, although I haven't explored this in detail:

[image]

**EDIT: This is the closest I've come to finding logs for the client:**

I also noted there seems are some kind of log files generated in the `%Temp%\VSLogs` folder of the form `*.LSPClient.MockLanguageExtension.FooLanguageClient.*.svclog`